# Use remote database with Backbone autocomplete script

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I want to use the script found on this [page](http://rockyj.in/2012/05/25/intro_to_backbone_jQuery.html) for my autocomplete function. The explanation is quite clear and it's working with my own database, currently I'm pulling up movie titles from my own database. But what I want to achieve is a list of movie titles from the TMDB (or other) database.

The movie search url for the TMDB api is `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=star+wars` where star+wars is the value of the input field.

Could someone explain or give an example on how I would achieve this?

```
%h1 Find Users
%form{:action => "find", :method => "get"}
  %input#movie-input{:placeholder => "Enter Name", :type => "text"}/
#movie-selection{:style => "margin-top:10px;"}

:javascript
  $(function() {

    var MovieList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ //Line 11
      url: '/api/movies.json',
      parse: function(response) {
        return response;
      }
    });

    var movies = new MovieList(); //Line 26
    movies.fetch({async: false});
    var movieNames = movies.pluck("title");

    $("#movie-input").autocomplete({ //Line 30
      source : movieNames,
      minLength : 2
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just created a working fiddle with the API given in question :
http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/dxpowx27/2/

For the sake of completion, here's what it looks like :

```
var MoviesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url:function(){
        return "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query="+this.query;
    },
    parse:function(response){
        return response.results;
    },
    setQuery:function(query){
        this.query=encodeURIComponent(query);
    }
});

var myCollection = new MoviesCollection();
myCollection.setQuery('star wars');

myCollection.fetch().done(function(){
    alert('fetch complete : '+myCollection.length);
    //$("#search_container").html(JSON.stringify(myCollection.toJSON()));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but I'm afraid I need a bit more explanation. In your Fiddle, did you put a part in the CSS for me to figure out what to do with it? Also I'm having some problems with rendering the template as you can see here > http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/26/

Comment: updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/dxpowx27/2/), sorry about the CSS, I forked from an existing code & overlooked to remove it.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add the collection code to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/26/), there's nothing being fetched.

Comment: What if I want to create a event that does the fetch request? Should I create a Backbone view and put the event in there? I tried to give an example of what I'm trying to do > http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/31/

Comment: yeah, you can create a Backbone View and handle the event in there. In the event handler, call the `collection.fetch()`

Comment: Alright, quick question then. I can't create a click event on a element that's on the body right? The element that's being targetted in the backbone has to be a template that's being redered by the view.

Comment: yes, the element triggering the click has to be in the view's el. Although, you can tie the Backbone view to body also ;)>

Comment: After messing around for a bit I got the rendering of the template done. But I'm not sure how to fetch the collection, could you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/dxpowx27/64/